# Limits of promo codes generation

Tags: magento2

I have two questions regarding the generation of promo codes:

1. Is there a limit on how many promo codes can be generated in backend?
2. Is there a limit on how many promo codes can be generated **per store view**?

I was able to generate 2 million promo codes, I am just wondering if for higher values Magento will also perform the operation well.

Thank you,

Carla

Answer (score 0):

2 million promo codes too much promotion code as per as my idea.

How Much promo codes can generate at Magento 2, it is totally depends on much your load can support your MySQL server and How much load can support your server.

**Mysql limitation**

Magento save generate coupon code store at **salesrule_coupon** table at database and Database Engine for this table **InnoDB**.It has a limitation. See limation at

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350581/how-many-rows-are-too-many-for-a-mysql-table

So, you have to take care of this limitation.